# Expression engine: search in grid-fields does not work

Tags: search, grid, expressionengine, fieldtype

I have built my faq-section with a grid that contains two columns, question and answer. I don't get search results from my grid-fields in entries. So my questions are unfortunately not searchable ...

In the fieldgroup the grid-Field itself and all grid-columns are marked as searchable.

The searchform has search_in="everywhere" and all Channels are activated.

The results-Code is

```
    <p>Keyword: {exp:search:keywords} - {exp:search:total_results}{total_results}{/exp:search:total_results}</p>  
<ul>
    {exp:search:search_results}
            <li><a href="{auto_path}">{title}{grid_budgetgruppen}</a></strong> from <em>{channel}</em><br/>{excerpt}<br/></li>
    {/exp:search:search_results}
</ul>
```

All other content gives proper results.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Better to head over [here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/) and repost.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to set the field and at least one of its columns as searchable. The values of the chosen column will be concatenated on a database column specially to be searched.